# limit as norm goes to infinity

Tags: limits, normed-spaces

Find the limit $\lim_{||(x,y)||\to \infty} \frac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2}$. If we go along a path y=0 the function goes to 0, so if the limit exists it must be 0.

That is we need to find a K so that for each $\epsilon$ if ||(x,y)||>K than $|\frac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2}|<\epsilon$.
$\frac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^3+y^3}$

Comment: I suppose since all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^2$ it can be any norm.

Comment: Hint: Show that the denominator is greater than $\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin \theta)$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{x+y}{(x^2+y^2)-xy} 
= \frac{r\cos \theta + r \sin\theta}{r^2 - r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}
= \frac{1}{r}\frac{\cos\theta + \sin \theta}{1 - \tfrac12\sin(2\theta)}
\end{align}

Now using basic inequality $-1\leq \cos\theta,\sin\theta \leq 1$, we obtain
$$
-\frac{4}{3r} =\frac1r \frac{(-1)+(-1)}{1-\tfrac12(-1)}
\leq \frac1r \frac{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}{1-\tfrac12\sin(2\theta)}
\leq \frac1r \frac{(1)+(1)}{1-\tfrac12(1)}
= \frac{4}{r}$$
The bounds are independent of $\theta$, so
$$\lim_{r\to \infty}-\frac{4}{3r}
\leq \lim_{r\to\infty}\frac1r \frac{\cos\theta + \sin\theta}{1-\tfrac12\sin(2\theta)}
= \lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to\infty} \frac{x+y}{x^2+ - xy +y^2} 
\leq \lim_{r\to \infty} \frac{4}{r}$$

By the squeeze theorem:

$$
\lim_{\|(x,y)\|_2\to\infty}
\frac{x+y}{(x^2+y^2)-xy} 
=\lim_{r\to\infty}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\cos\theta + \sin \theta}{1 - \tfrac12\sin(2\theta)}
= 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Show the inequality $t^2-t+1\geq (1+t^2)/2$ (for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$) and use it to show that for all $x,y$ we have $x^2-xy+y^2\geq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$, and use to finish that $|x|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$